# php Pattern Matching for custom tags

Tags: php, tags, design-patterns, match

I am trying to replace all the tags in a file like `{{name:something}}` to some certain values.
Note that in `{{name::something}}` only something might warry. Like `{{name:title}}` or `{{name:content}}`. That "name" will always be there.

Anyway,
I used preg_match_all and preg_replace, it all worked out. I found the matches with this regular expression: `$patmatch="/{{name:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+}}/";`

**My problem is the following:**

When a tag like this does not match the pattern (it has a syntax error), like `{{notname:something}}` or `{{name something}}` or `{{ }}` i must throw an exception.
How do i know if the tag is there, but with a syntax error?

Can i somehow make another pattern search to check if it's a tag (between `{{` and `}}`) and if it's not like `{{name:something}}`?

Any help would be appreciated,
Thanks!

Answer (score 1):

Off the top of my head:

```
if(strpos($text, '{{name:') === false)
{
    //exception
}
else
{
    //properly formatted text
}
```

Something like that?

Comment: Well, almost. You see, the preg_match_all() function will get me only the right matches. The properly formatted texts. But i need to also find the incorrect ones and throw an exception if i find any.

Comment: Thank you all, i solved the problem with NFLineast's ideea.

I just preg_match_all() on every $patmatch="/{{[a-zA-Z0-9.:_-]+}}/"; (basically every {{ }} ) and then i just check if(strpos($text, '{{name:') === false) as NFLineast said.

Thanks again, all of your solutions are good, i will try the others aswell i think :)

Darksody.

Comment: Excellent. strpos() is also a lot less resource hungry than preg_match()... :)

Answer (score 1):

Other answers only check if that tag is inside content, this one checks for true validity:

Assuming that you have $content variable that holds contents of file, you can temporarily store validation data which will be like that:

```
$validation = preg_replace("/{{name:[a-zA-Z0-9._-]+}}/","",$content);
```

So you will have cotents stripped off valid tags and now you want to look for invalid tag, depending on how strict you want it, you can use one of theese:

```
if(preg_match('/{{name:[^}]*}}/', $validation)) //found error tag
//alternatively you might want to check for typos like "nmae":
if(preg_match('/{{[^}]*}}/', $validation)) //found error tag
```

Answer (score 0):

Maybe you can use something like subpattern, naming and check the result